# There aren't many vs. there aren't a lot of

Tags: word-choice, verbs, negation

I have field practice in a school now, and I had an argument with a teacher of English there. She says **'there aren't a lot of [...]'** is incorrect, and **'there aren't many'** should be used instead.
I haven't heard of any such rule in the 16 years I'm studying English, so I'm doubting that.

Could you tell me which variant is more preferable?

Comment: Thanks for the correction :)

She said that 'a lot of' couldn't be used in negatives, that's what I'm saying. Is she right?

Comment: I've not come across such a rule, though it's true that some speakers dislike this use of "lot" (and "lots") preferring "many" and "much". Incidentally, be careful about the grammar: "there aren't a lot of" and "there aren't many" are parsed quite differently.

Comment: @BillJ What you state is simply not true. It depends, and I have explained all this. **No one would say**, for example: I have much money. **They would say**: I have a lot of money or lots of money. There aren't a lot of dogs on the lawn. There aren't many dogs on the lawn.  = both mean the exact same thing.

Comment: @Lambie - "Hoboken may have had much money stolen from its treasury" _New York Times_, March 21, 1889

Comment: @BillJ - I might say that 'a lot of' is a bit less formal than 'many'; perhaps this is the teacher's objection. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/lots-a-lot-plenty) lists the phrase along with 'lots of', 'plenty of',  as less formal, and  'a large number of' as more formal alternatives to 'many'

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, but notice: *much money **stolen** from its treasury*. Also, I don't think that that is contemporary or spoken (1889). That sentence is written English, afaik. "many is formal". What is not formal is a lot of and lots of. I repeat: in English today, no one goes around **saying:** I have much money. In writing: Much money etc. at the head yes, I think you should read my answer more carefully. If you haven't taught ESL, you might not have encountered all these ins and outs of these spoken language issues.

Comment: I made a big effort to put my answer in specific contexts. "I have much patience [buzzer re spoken English use of much in a declarative of this kind] when interacting here".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I can see where the OP is coming from. Some ESL on-line material advises learners to use "a lot of" in positive statements, and "much" / "many" in negatives and interrogatives, which presumably is why the OP's teacher says that negatives with "a lot of" are wrong. "From what I read, "a lot of" isn't strongly conversational/casual in style; instead, there's merely some dispreference for using it in very formal writing. There may even be some difference in meaning, cf.  "Do you want a lot of pizza"? vs "Do you want much pizza? Can you detect a slight difference?

Comment: @BillJ - I can see 'do you want much pizza?' having a negative expectation (an implied 'I hope not').

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  "Do you want a lot of pizza"? (I expect you want to eat a lot). "Do you want much pizza?" This sounds unusual, as though I expect you don't want to eat much.

Comment: Either “there aren’t many” or “there aren’t a lot” sound fine to me (in American English). The second one is more informal.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but she is wrong.

**Affirmative**:

- There are many dogs on the lawn.
- There are lots of dogs on the lawn.
- There are a lot of dogs on the lawn.   All those mean the mean the same thing.

**Negative**:

- There aren't many dogs on the lawn.
- There aren't lots of dogs on the lawn.
- There aren't a lot of dogs on the lawn.
- So do those.

**BUT**: "**There is a lot of** ***brouhaha*** about this issue". [Also, "there are" can be: There're] "a lot of" can go with *there is* or *there are* depending on whether the noun that comes after it is countable or uncountable.

**But here's the trick in the affirmative**: We **normally** do not use: *I have much money*. [in spoken English]. There, we'd only most likely say: **I have a lot of or lots of money**. But you might say: They have many flaws. (flaws is countable).

The adjective "much" is infrequently heard in affirmative sentences using phrases such as "much time, much money, much coffee, etc. We would not say: I have much time on my hands. "lots of or a lot of" is preferred there. But **in the negative**, it is frequent: **I don't have much time on my hands.**

Comment: Also, not negative,  but intensified: too much.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Do you mean like this: I have too much money? That is not just much is it? In all fairness,  one can't  answer every single thing, especially when it was not even asked about.

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing with your post, which I upvoted, just adding a thought.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Right-o. Just don't be so terse because I get it but the OP might not....

Comment: Ok, continuing from your last line, "But in the negative it is frequent: I don't have much time on my hands." Also, positive but intensified: I have too much time on my hands. (Which seems to be true.)

Comment: All your examples are declaratives. The contrast you make in your examples is between positive and negative declaratives.

Comment: No one caught me out, just myself: I meant to say **affirmative**, not declarative. Declarative affirmative would have been OK. I have now changed it.

Comment: Also, "much" is often used in an inerogative sense "Is there much snow on the ground?" or "Do you think there will be much traffic today?"

Comment: @DavidSiegel My answer only applies to the what the OP asked. It is not an epistle on much.

Comment: @Lambie Quite true. There is nothing wrong with the answer IMO. I am merely adding information that might be of some, or perhaps even much, value to some readers.